# KKT Non-Negative-Condition

Tags: optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Is there any way of a graphic understanding of the non-negative condition in the KKT conditions? Why do I need this only for the inequality constraints?

Best Regards

Gesetzt

Comment: Are you referring to the "dual feasibility" conditions? (using the terminology from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want why the $\lambda$ has to be non-negative for an inequality constraint. Assuming this is what you want, consider the following first order expansion:

$f(x+d) \approx f(x) + \nabla f^T d$ (**by Taylor's theorem**), and

$c(x+d) \approx c(x) + \nabla c^T d$ (**by Taylor's theorem**)

where $c$ is the constraint function (assumed $\geq0$), $f$ is the function you are trying to minimise and $d$ is the direction of descent.

Now, for a feasible direction, $\nabla f^T d \lt0$ (**because you want a decrease in the function**) and $\nabla c^T d \geq0$ (**because you want to stay feasible**). Now, when won't one have a feasible $d$?

Only when, $\nabla f(x)= \lambda*\nabla c(x)$ where $\lambda \geq0$. Pictorially, the following figure may help you:
[courtesy of Numerical Optimisation by Nocedal and Wright](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbWZ4.png)

Now what happens if $\lambda \lt0?$ You have the whole open half space as feasible and you don't reach a solution.